# Поиск по JSON файлу

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Нашел готовый код:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");//i
  $.getJSON('json_.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, val){
    if (val.title.search(expression))
    {
     $('#result').append(' '+val.title+' ');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
</script>
```

Поиск работает криво, при вводе запроса, отображает почти все, что есть в базе.
Пожалуйста, помогите исправить , может где-то есть рабочий готовый скрипт?
Я не нашел его ни в гугле ни в яндексе.

Спасибо!

Comment: как соотносятся понятия "база" и "JSON файл" в Вашем вопросе?

Comment: база в json файле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете значение, возвращаемое методом `String.search`:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

```
if (val.title.search(expression) != -1)
{ 
  ...
}
```